# PHPExcel Releasing Memory after storing Excel File

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

This code is to store generated excels file with PHP Excel library

> "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"

There are 30k rows of transaction data and each transaction has sub-data. The goal is to generate transactions report document which is being grouped by months (1 month = 1 Excel File). 15k of transactions has been set as the limit per sheet (it automatically generate a new sheet if the limit has been exceeded).

As I tried to log the memory usage, the process has taken up a load of memory. Here are the following details regarding memory usage.

First state of memory : **10 MB**

First Excel file(First Month) Generated memory state : **88 MB**

**Expected** memory state after the first excel file has been stored : as the same as the the first state which is **10 MB**

**Actual** memory state after the first excel file has been stored : **60 MB**

Which means that phpexcel didn't fully release the memory even after the first file has been generated and stored.

Supposedly The PHP excel should release the memory after the first file has been generated. The goal is to generate at least 150k rows transactions into separated excel files but within this situation, I believe it wont be possible because it will take a lot of memory usage.

Any solution that can be done in order to avoid memory issue in generating PHP excel files?

The code that in order to generate the excel files is shown below.
Thank you in advance.

```
    $counter = 0;
    // Loop through months
    foreach ($period as $month) {
        $numberOfPages = 1;
        $startOfMonth = $monthLoops === 0 ? Carbon::parse($export->startDate) : $month->copy()->startOfMonth();
        $endOfMonth = $monthLoops === $numberOfMonths ? Carbon::parse($export->endDate) : $month->copy()->endOfmonth();
        $monthName = $month->format('F');

        // do the first call and get number of records and calculate pages
        list($transactions, $aggregations, $numberOfTransactions) = $this->getTransactionsCall($datalakeSalesTransactionRepository, $companyUuid, $export, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth, 1, 1, null, 1);

        if ($transactions) {
            // generate first datalake excel call
            $objPHPExcel = Excel::create("Laporan Transaksi Penjualan $monthName ".$startOfMonth->year, function ($excel) use ($export, &$counter, $totalTransactionsPerSheet, $numberOfPages, $datalakeSalesTransactionRepository, $companyUuid, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth, $perPage, $transactions, $aggregations, $numberOfTransactions) {
                $page = 1;
                // calculate pages and sheets
                $sheetLoop = 1;
                $numberOfPages = $numberOfTransactions !== 0 ? (int) ceil($numberOfTransactions/$perPage) : 1;
                $numberOfSheets =$numberOfTransactions !== 0 ? (int) ceil($numberOfTransactions/$totalTransactionsPerSheet) : 1;

                // generate all sheets in one excel
                for ($sheetLoop; $sheetLoop <= $numberOfSheets; $sheetLoop++) {
                    // generate sheets if total of transactions in one excel exceed limit of totalRows per sheet chunk by perPage
                    $this->currentRow = 1;
                    $numberOfTransactionsInOneSheet = 0;

                    $excel->sheet("$export->myTitle-$sheetLoop", function ($sheet) use ($export, $aggregations, $numberOfTransactionsInOneSheet, &$counter, $totalTransactionsPerSheet, &$page, $numberOfPages, $datalakeSalesTransactionRepository, $companyUuid, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth, $perPage) {
                        // loop through calls per 200 items to avoid memory usage issue
                        $header = $this->getHeader($export, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth);

                        foreach ($header as $row) {
                            $sheet->row($this->currentRow++, $row);
                        }

                        while ($page <= $numberOfPages) {
                            $transactions = $this->getTransactionsCall($datalakeSalesTransactionRepository, $companyUuid, $export, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth, $page, $perPage, 1);

                            foreach ($transactions as $keyTrx => $transaction) {
                                $counter++;
                                $this->generateRow($transaction, $keyTrx, $sheet);
                                \Log::info(array('transactions' => $counter, $startOfMonth->month));
                                \Log::info(memory_get_usage()/1000000);
                            }


                            $numberOfTransactionsInOneSheet += $perPage;
                            $page++;

                            if ($numberOfTransactionsInOneSheet >= $totalTransactionsPerSheet) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        $this->setTotal($aggregations);
                        $this->setUpSheet($sheet);
                    });
                }

                $this->getDatalakeDownpaymentSheet($excel, $export, $companyUuid, $numberOfPages, $perPage, $startOfMonth, $endOfMonth, $datalakeSalesTransactionRepository);
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            });

            $objPHPExcel->store($export->extension, $folderPath);

            $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
            $objPHPExcel->garbageCollect();
            unset($objPHPExcel);
        }

        $monthLoops++;
    }
```

I tried to release the memory after the file has been stored with this pieces of code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
        $objPHPExcel->store($export->extension, $folderPath);

        $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
        $objPHPExcel->garbageCollect();
        unset($objPHPExcel);
```